# Create widget in dashboard displaying a custom user field?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I'm trying to follow this tutorial but I can't get it to work. My best hypothesis is that because the code is 4 years old, some function in it might have been deprecated... And the code provided there needs some minor update.

Anybody has any ideas?

Here's the link I'm referring to: [How to Make a Custom Dashboard Widget to Display Custom Notification from Admin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51591/how-to-make-a-custom-dashboard-widget-to-display-custom-notification-from-admin#new-answer?newreg=60c9e7554a384a2dbbab8f528d92c6c1)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE - can you clarify which of the techniques you _have_ tried, ideally update your question with some code samples, and elaborate on "can't get it to work" (were you getting errors? did it partially work? at what point did you get stuck) Also please make sure you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and again, update your question with any errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Here's a link where I explain how I solved it and how the final code looked like:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/customize-dashboard-widgets-for-individual-users-1?replies=11